# Adding Channel Overwrites for user in Discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am trying to create a channel overwrite for my bot so it can send the message in the channel that the channel is locked for the @everyone role

```
    @commands.command()
    @has_permissions(manage_channels=True)
    async def lock(self, ctx):
        member = discord.Member.id(712885407993561169)
        await ctx.channel.set_permissions(ctx.guild.default_role, send_messages=False, read_messages=False)
        await ctx.channel.set_permissions(member, send_messages=True, read_messages=True)
        await ctx.send(':greentick: Locked down ' + ctx.channel.name)
```

Comment: What sort of errors are you encountering? If you're not getting any errors, what is the result of this code and what did you expect it to do instead?

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
    @commands.command()
    @commands.has_permissions(manage_channels=True)
    async def lock(self, ctx: commands.Context):
        overwrites = ctx.channel.overwrites_for(ctx.guild.default_role)
        overwrites.read_messages, overwrites.send_messages = False, False
        await ctx.channel.set_permissions(ctx.guild.default_role, overwrite=overwrites)
        overwrites = ctx.channel.overwrites_for(ctx.me)
        overwrites.send_messages, overwrites.read_messages = True, True
        await ctx.channel.set_permissions(ctx.me, overwrite=overwrites)
```